# Greedy Algorithm vs Nearest Neighbor Algorithm

Tags: nearest-neighbor, greedy, traveling-salesman

I'm doing an assignment on Travelling Salesman and I want to know the difference between the Greedy Algorithm and the Nearest Neighbor algorithm. I looked it up and they seemed almost the same to me. And there weren't any good resources tha compared them. What is their difference?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'm having a hard time finding the similarity :) You talk about two very different algorithms here, for different kinds of problems.

Greedy algorithm is being used mainly for graphs, as it's supposed to solve staged-problems, when each stage requires us to make a decision. For example, when trying to find the shortest way from one point to another, it would choose each time the closest point to the current point it stands at.

K-NN is a lazy classification algorithm, being used a lot in machine learning problems. It calculates the class for a value depending on its distance from the k closest points in the set.

Thinking about it, you can actually say that each stage of the greedy algorithm uses a 1-Nearest-Neighbours algorithm to find the closest point, but it's pretty ridiculous... :)

Hope it's understandable!